# How do you setup special characters for Identity Core LoginPath?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity Core for authentication.  I have an AngularJS SPA with a login route (UI-Router).  My user's are getting routed to an escaped URL instead of the real URL.

My login path is set to "/#!/login", but my users are being routed to: "/%23!/login" which causes a 401 in the browser.

I've tried using System.Uri.EscapeDataString, System.Uri.EscapeUriString and without escaping at all with no luck.

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddCookie(cookie => 
{
    cookie.LoginPath = System.Uri.EscapeDataString("/#!/login");
})
```

**AngularJS Route**

```
.state('login', {
        url: 'login',
        views: {
            '': { templateUrl: './Home/login.html', controller: "loginController" }
        }
    })
```

I've confirmed the server is generating a 302 response with the following location: "http://localhost:63939/%23!/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fadministrator".  So the server is definitely escaping the "#!" and it is not something the browser is doing.

Comment: Did you enable HTML 5 mode?

Comment: This isn't an issue on the angular side.  The browser is getting a 401 because "/%23!/login" doesn't exist.

Comment: Try this `url: '#/login'` instead of `url: 'login'`

Comment: The issue is not on the angular side so changing the angular route url won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've been able to figure out is to unescape the RedirectUri in the OnRedirectToLogin cookie authentication event.  There has got to be a better way.

```
cookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
{
    OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
 context.Response.Redirect(System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(context.RedirectUri));
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
};
```